# Should I care docker image security?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, image, security, docker

I uploaded a rails image to a cloud Iaas vendor, and the vendor has a function that they can scan the image for security. The result scared me that a lot of high-level bugs that seems to relate to OS. SO my question is that should I care about image security? If yes, to which extend?
Here is the screenshot for details, if you guys can read Chinese.[image]

Comment: Please refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481093/why-are-there-so-many-docker-images-with-vulnerabilities/42485021#42485021 it may solve your question. The vulnerabilities are not docker-specific, so you will have them even without (if you are using same versions).